# Applications loading slightly more slowly after shrinking Debian 9 root partition

Tags: debian, filesystems, partition, xfce, gparted

I have a 250 GB Samsung Pro SSD in my Lenovo desktop. Initially Debian 9 was using the whole disk. Recently I decided to shrink my Debian partition and create two more partitions, one a shared data partition for my Nextcloud, and on the last partition I installed Xubuntu 19.04 with the Xfce 4.14 pre-release PPA installed. In order to do so, I booted a live USB, loaded GParted, and shrunk my Debian partition down to 46 GB (21 GB used, 13 GB available). The entire OS is in one partition. I use fstab to mount my Nextcloud partition in my home directory.

Since shrinking my Debian partition, I have noticed that applications load more slowly. This is very slight, but it is still enough to bother me. Before in Debian and in Xubuntu 19.04 currently, for example, launching Xfce4 Terminal after reboot is basically instant. However, now in Debian there is about a 400-600 millisecond delay. It is the same for other applications in Debian. I created a new user, logged in there, and had the same result. So, it is not an issue with my home profile. I have tried reinstalling applications but no luck. The disk is healthy after running a disk health test. Xubuntu 19.04 is super fast as Debian was before the partition resize. It must have something to do with shrinking the Debian partition / root file system. Any ideas on how this could be solved?

Comment: Maybe shrinking your partition caused some fragmentation, due to the way ext4 file systems write data on the disk? What does `fsck` tell you?

Comment: I ran `fsck` and I defragmented with `e4defrag`. There was not any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xfce in Appearance I changed the Style and Icons. Then in Window Manager I changed the Style. Now applications load just as fast as before. I am not sure why.